# Case insensitive with Exact Search term Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to make a query that searches for the exact keyword but case insensitively.

It works fine but the issue that it searches for the whole keywords into the DB that CONTAINS my search term.

```
mongoTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("resourceID").regex(id, "i")), Resource.class);
```

I need to make like the follwoing script but in java:

```
db.stuff.find( { foo: /^bar$/i } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Resource resource = mongoTemplateGoVacation.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("resourceID").regex("^"+id+"$", "i")), Resource.class);